# Recommendations on Updating MySql database from Checkbox values in a HTML

Tags: java, html, mysql, ajax, struts

I'm having a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WphY5.jpg) with the contents retrieved from my MYSQL DB. Now, below the TH row I have a row for searching through the table column wise. I have shown a sample search through the table.

The user of this application might check some checkboxes after doing some search (and according to some rules that satisfies research requirements). Now, I would like to have a submit [update records] button below this table which on clicking updates the corresponding records - against which the checkbox has been selected to update the value of CheckBox column - "Accepted"in this case.

For you information, I'm using struts and so to do this I will have write a struts action class to handle this. I also considered AJAX to update this asynchronously in the back-end. I would like suggestions from people on the best practice to do this.

[image]

Comment: It would probably be easiest to loop through the records that are checked with your form processing script and update the database that way.

Comment: sorry to be naive, But I understood the former part - to write a JQUERY/JS script to get all the records that has the check-box checked/selected.In latter statement, do you mean to say that I should update database, through AJAX ? If you don't mind could you elaborate the latter part - as a way of doing it.Thanks in advance,Sir.

Comment: You will need to update the database with the platform you are using. You can get the values of the checkboxes with jQuery/JS, but to update the database you will need to use an update script in struts. There is probably a mechanism to read json data in struts so you can encode the checkbox data in json and decode + update the db in struts. Sorry I'm not more familiar with struts!

Comment: @Tomanow Using jQuery/JS, then JSON + ajax to transmit data would work perfectly fine, but there are already basic mechanisms to handle a form submit in java-ee. For information, struts is basically a framework made handle a Model (java bean) / View (jsp) / Controller (servlet) pattern.

Comment: Your problem is about setting values in a list, when submitting the form. It's called indexed properties. You may currently have a list in your ActionForm, and you want the property "accepted" to be set for each line when submitting the form, then updating in DB the lines which have this property set to "true". Am I wrong ? If not please show the ActionForm code, and a bit of JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the stack you have described, you have a web application with Struts on the server. When a user chooses to update the records you can either post the data using a html form, or use Ajax calls. Irrespective of how the data is sent, you will have Struts code to process the information and update the database. The only difference is in how the data got there. It's up to you to decide which makes more sense.